# Scroll Listview with respect to the handler movement in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a list view and a Indicator view inside a Row widget as in the image.Please check the image from the link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B0Il.png

I need to swipe the indicator up and down and with respect to the movement , the listview item should get selected according to the position of the indicator.
the list items is also selectable which should move the indicator as well.(for example , If I select item 4 ,the indicator should move to the position aligned with item 4).both cases should work.

My sample code is given below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Indicator Animation Example'),
        ),
        body: IndicatorListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IndicatorListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<IndicatorListView> createState() => _IndicatorListViewState();
}

class _IndicatorListViewState extends State<IndicatorListView> {
  int selectedIndex = -1;
  int itemCount = 10;
  List<GlobalKey> _keys = [];
  Offset? _selectedOffset;
   
  @override
  void initState() {
    _keys = List<GlobalKey>.generate(itemCount, (index) => GlobalKey());
    
    super.initState();
  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              key: _keys[index],
              title: Text('Item $index'),
              selected: index == selectedIndex,
              onTap: () {
                var renderBox = _keys[index].currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                _selectedOffset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          top: (_selectedOffset?.dy??0) - 35,
          right: 0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: Container(
            height: 5,
            width: 29,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me out.